# Non-intersection of two n-dimentional pytorch tensors

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, pytorch, intersection

Thanks everyone in advance for your help! What I'm trying to do in PyTorch is to compute non-intersection ( lets call it `torch.nonintersection`) for tensors of many dimenstions (without for loops because I want it to be effectively performed on GPU). So here is the example how it should work:

```
a = torch.tensor([[ 0.,  0.], [ 0.,  1.], [ 0.,  2.], [ 1.,  0.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  2.], [ 1.,  3.], 
                  [ 2.,  0.], [ 2.,  1.], [ 2.,  2.]])
b = torch.tensor([[ 2.,  0.], [ 2.,  1.], [ 2.,  2.], [ 1.,  0.], [ 1.,  1.], [ 1.,  2.], [ 1.,  3.]])

torch.spec_unique(a,b) = torch.tensor([ 0.,  0.], [ 0.,  1.], [ 0.,  2.])
```

I have analogs with for loops, but they take too much time right now. Any Ideas how it can be done? Much appreciated!

Comment: Is that just the symmetric difference?

Comment: @phipsgabler absolutely, I was just didn't know this term previously. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape of `a` and `b` is different in your case (`a` is `(10, 2)`, while `b` is `(7, 2)`), so you have to "cut" the bigger tensor to the size of the smaller one. Function below handles it with simple `if` (it won't slow down your computations):

```
def non_intersection(a, b):
    if a.shape[0] > b.shape[0]:
        return torch.nonzero(a[: b.shape[0]] != b, as_tuple=False)
    return torch.nonzero(b[: a.shape[0]] != a, as_tuple=False)
```

This would return:

```
tensor([[0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]])
```

So the columns are in opposite order. If you wish to get columns just like in your example you can do this on `non_intersection` output:

```
torch.index_select(non_intersection(a, b), 1, torch.tensor([1, 0])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is really what I was searching for! But in my case I will consider padding with some dummy data.

Comment: @Kochiev Leon It would be pretty wasteful to pad it as you can be sure there is no intersection there. You could pad final result with zeros though.

Comment: Yep, it seems like i didn't catch what was it about at first glance. Thanks once again!